# Add text/element/variable or other things into a div element after being redirected to a new page

Tags: jquery, redirect, click, window.open

I am trying to insert text into a div element which has an id... I am using window.open with jQuery but this isn't working. Does anybody knows how to do this or an alternative? I will appreciate any info. Thanks
This is what I have so far:

```
$("button").click(function() {

window.open('page2.html', '_blank');

$("#imgdiv").html("hello");


})
```

Comment: is the `imgdiv` in the new window? if so, this action is called when the button is clicked, not when the new window is opened.

Comment: Mech. Oh, that's right. What would I need in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not working is because your code fully executes immediately as the button is clicked and before the new window is opened. You'll want to conduct a check when the window is open by validating the URL (`window.location.href`). The below code uses `indexOf` to determine if the url contains `page2.html`. If found, an `#imgdiv` will be updated.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() { 
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("page2.html") > -1) {
      $("#imgdiv").html("hello");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Mech. Ok, but I don't want to make an alert if the page is found. I want to show some text on the opened page

Comment: That was just to show you when it triggers :) I will update it now.

Comment: Mech. Great. I want to select a div with an id and put content in that div